# IE displays my code instead of my webpage, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

It works fine in Chrome but in IE it shoots back code...I think it has to do with quirks mode but I cannot seem to find the exact problem.

[my trouble page](http://asolutionaday.com/test/Warrior.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here, I believe, is with your document being identified as UTF-8 encoded by the HTTP Response header, but arriving with a [BOM](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php) that suggests it is UTF-16 encoded. Internet Explorer 10 and 11 give more weight to the header, than to the BOM. As a result, the UTF-16 document is read as UTF-8, which results in numerous null characters being added after nearly ever byte, causing your markup to be parsed as general text.

You can see the BOM (`FF FE`, "ÿþ"), and the null characters (`00`) in the following view:

[image]

Note the representation of your doctype. The null characters cause it to be broken up, so as not to be parsed as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

But instead, like this (*. represents null characters*):

```
<.!.D.O.C.T.Y.P.E. .h.t.m.l.>
```

This pattern is repeated throughout the *entire* document, thus no part of it is interpreted as HTML, making all of it be rendered as basic text:

[image]

When saving your document, ensure that you are saving as UTF-8. I should note as well that Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer's successor, does not behave the same way. Microsoft Edge gives the BOM (declaring UTF-16 encoding) precedence over the `charset` instructions in the header, thus rendering the page properly.

I came across numerous reports claiming that Notepad (which you reportedly used) *always* inserts a BOM. I would encourage you to avoid Notepad as an editor during web-development. Instead, use something like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Comment: That's a lot of extra ...'s, OK so I should used utf-8 not ANSI coding? After more testing it only fixed the problem on some IE browsers....err ummm I don't even think utf-16 was a choice in my note pad. I am mobile ATM so will have to double check later.

Comment: Another question I frequently use android which is why note pad is useful. Can I still build on notepad saving as text then copy paste when at home into vs studio to save q clean html?

Comment: You can use Notepad if you like, just remember to select the UTF-8 option when saving. That being said, Notepad isn't built for web development, and will ultimately slow you down, causing more problems than it solves.

Comment: Thanks so much I will save as utf-8 in about 8 hours and hopefully that will fix it all. I use an android program turbo editor and at the desktop I use a variety of windows systems but the most frequent is windows 8.1 I guess I've just stuck with notepad because it is already on all windows systems which is nice when hopping between desks/devices. I will probably give visual studio code a spin and if I can intergrate itneffeciently with my workflow then permanently switch to that system. Lack of markup was making debugging tedious anyways so I probably should have done this a while back.

Comment: Ok I did not try utf-8 lol. Instead I got visual studio code and used that to generate the htm file and now everything is good!

Comment: @Faugaun That's awesome news. If you'd like a deep dive into Visual Studio Code, [John Papa](https://twitter.com/John_Papa) recently did a [one-hour walk-through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3tPWAq74v4).

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like that IE (Edge) got some problems displaying this htm-file.
When I use the exact same source code but as a html-file. IE is displaying it fine. When I use developer Tools IE 10 and below can display it correctly as well.

You should know that there is one error caused by multiple body tags. you should definitely avoid this!!

Edit:
you can also try to add this to your head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you just change it from <html> to <html-file> ??

Comment: your file is named like this yourfilename.htm but you should try yourfilename.html
maybe you need to select 'show hidden files, folder, and drives' and also uncheck hide protected operating system files in windows settings

Comment: Changed to html and consolidated to a single body tag still displaying as code http://asolutionaday.com/test/Warrior2.html

Comment: It's loading offline in IE but not once FTP'd to my hosting account.

Comment: Maybe your code was messed up or something. Everything is fine when I try it on my webserver and IE
http://whatsapp.tom-oliver.eu/test.html

Comment: I'm completely baffled, I copy your source from your page which works in my browser. Then save as Warrior.htm and Warrior.html both ways and it continues to display code when i load at my url...In notepad I save under all files, coding = unicode . Is it the coding type ?

Comment: Ok, Changed it to ANSI coding and it works, no other changes from my beginning code. I will need to go read more to understand why this fixed it but for now I'm ecstatic that it is fixed. I did change the <body> as you suggested.